Как сделать так, что бы оружие, созданное игроком, отображалось в анимаци
Я хочу добавить в игру возможность самому собирать оружие из рукояти, гарды и клинка. Вопрос в том, как сделать так, что бы собранное оружие появлялось в анимации атаки, бега и т.д? Например, условный меч будет висеть у игрока на спине и покачиваться из-за бега. Но не могу же я добавлять анимацию покачивания для всех вариаций оружия. Подскажите, как лучше сделать.

не разбираюсь в вашей технологии, но из практики) игрушка которой более 15 лет имеет размер 9 гб, пак моделек 2 гб+,  пак с модельками построения персонажа более 400 мб) тоесть каждый меч, посох или лук имеет свою модель, которая имеет свою анимацию (их рисуют на заказ активно) так же и полеты, текстуры объектов зданий и тд) анимация скиллов так же для каждого своя..
Общий алгоритм один, прописывается общее поведение покачивания и тд, а туда уже подгружаете нужное оружие) как-то так мб

Совершенству нет предела, но в простом случае - делаете анимацию для модели стандартного меча и подменяете его части на другие. До тех пор, пока подмены незначительные, никто не заметит подвоха. А если кто-то заменит лезвие на зубочистку, а гарду на пятиэтажку - никакой подход не спасет :-)
Я у себя ещё делал модификатор "веса" предмета. Чем предмет тяжелее, тем меньше выражено покачивание и т.п. Но это лишь костыль. Хотя, как известно, все игры это smoke and mirrors да куча костылей :-)
